# Java - Returning a value

Tags: java, return

Change your program, so that instead of displaying all the array elements, it asks the user to input a number, then displays just that element. To get this to work, you will need to use Scanner to return an int value.

The above states what i need to do, and the code shows my current status. Not sure really how to go about this , cheers.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * Purpose: Introduction to data structures
 * @author p'o'p'
 *
 */
public class StudentNames{

    public static void main(String[] args){         
        String[] names = new String[8];                                        
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
        for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){
            System.out.println( "Enter student name:" );                            
            names[ i ] = s.next();                          
        }                        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ ){               
            System.out.println(" Input your chosen number" );
            System.out.println("Student name:"+ names[ i ]);         
            int index = i;
            System.out.println( index );                              
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the program currently doing, which specific bits are the problem?

Comment: You won't learn anything if we just give you the solution. So try to solve it yourself and come back with a question if there is a specific problem.

Comment: Hint: Scanner has a method that returns an int.

Comment: To be more clear; the idea of a stack overflow question isn't: "This code isn't working, why?" but should be "I need to do x, here is my attempt to do x, but instead y happened" (where x is a **small specific** task, and y is something bad)

Comment: There are two parts in your program, the first part reads input and stores it in an array. The second part outputs all array elements. I think this should be enough to give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

"it asks the user to input a number"
You have a scanner object (Good start!)  Now you need to use it to recieve input. 
Looking [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) we can see the methods
available for the scanner.  You need to select one that will allow you to recieve a whole number as input (If you are still not sure I expect there are many scanner examples on the internet and indeed on this site)

"then displays just that element."
When you use a for loop over an array to print the value, you are basically doing this

```
System.out.println("Student name:"+ names[1])
System.out.println("Student name:"+ names[2])
System.out.println("Student name:"+ names[3])
And so on...
```

This shows that when you access each element of the array, you are using a
number to reference each of the stored elements.  From this we can see that once you have 
a number within the length of the array, you can access that element.  So once you have obtained a number from input,
by combining it with 1 of the above statements you should reach your desired output.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code,not the efficient one,i just modified your code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
*
* Purpose: Introduction to data structures
* @author p'o'p'
*
*/

public class NewClass1{

public static void main(String[] args){         
    String[] names = new String[2];                                        
    Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
    for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){
        System.out.println( "Enter student name:" );                            
        names[ i ] = s.next();                          
    }
    System.out.println(" Input your chosen number" );
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        if(i==choice && choice < names.length)  
        {
         System.out.println("Student name:"+ names[ i ]);
         System.out.println(i);
        }
     }
}
```

}

Comment: It's generally better to give hints and ideas when answering homework questions, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Also; why the completely unnessisary for loop

Comment: @Richard Tingle....I'll consider your advice next time.!!